# Bigcommerce cart content in template

Tags: javascript, templates, cart, bigcommerce

I would like to get the visitors cart content, like quantity, product name, product sku, product price, etc., in a template to work with it via JavaScript because I would like to manage it with a 3rd party software.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done via Stencil in a more straightforward way, but there are no variables for the cart contents outside of cart.html. You could request query the contents of the cart page to build a cart display on alternative pages (similar to the theme goodvibes).

Comment: This looks good. I missed to mention that I would like to create an app for that purpose, sorry for this, and as I see the Stencil is good for theme developing or am I wrong?

Comment: Stencil is good for theme developing. You could create an app that only works on Stencil. We will be providing indicators of what framework apps are compatible with in the future.

Comment: And is there any Stencil and theme independent solution?

Comment: We are working on making it theme independent, but presently the answer is no.